# Immutable.js run on change

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have a library for modelling crossword puzzles, and I'd like to be able to update the grid (if you make a cell into a black cell, the clue numbers will change). I would like the update to happen automatically, so that if you do something like

`const p2 = puzzle.grid.setIn([0, 1, "isBlockCell"], true)`

then `p2` would already have the correct cell information. To do this, I would need to run a function to update the cells whenever `puzzle.grid` was changed. I haven't seen any way to do this; is it possible? Or do I need to find another way to do this? The puzzle is a Record instance. I was hoping that it would end up calling the constructor for the Record and I could do it there, but it doesn't seem to do that.

Comment: I thinking you need to implement Observable pattern: http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/observer-design-pattern

Comment: I don't think that would help here; `p2` would still have the unchanged grid data. Besides, I would still have to know when to fire the change event, which would require hooking into Immutable's change pipeline, which is what I'm trying to figure out here in the first place.